# crashlytics use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics framework!!

my app is working fine but some reason it always gives me error 
"crashlytics use of undeclared identifier"

```
   [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"**************************"];
```

Can anyone let me know what could be possible problem?

MY app is running fine even xcode shows error!

Comment: Try restarting Xcode.

Comment: Amar thanks!! Simple as that did trick!! So now Apple product can be solve like windows!! :-)